# Should a phonegap plugin be declared in the config.xml file?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I am a newbie in phonegap development so I have a couple of questions:

1) I am using the accelerometer plug-in. I read in the manual that i need to declare the plugin in the config.xml file in order to use it. However I noticed that even if i remove the declaration from the config.xml

```
<feature name="Accelerometer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener" />
</feature>
```

the accelerometer still works.

So I would like to ask you if in the phonegap 3.0.0 version , the use of the config.xml is obsolete. If that s the case then where is the binding takes place?

2) I use the android platform to build the app. In the project structure there are three config.xml files with different content:

- a) In the assets/www/phonegap-app-hello-world-3.0.0/www/config.xml
- b) In the assets/www/phonegap-app-hello-world-3.0.0/config.xml
- c) In the res/xml/config.xml

What s the use of each one of them ? Where I suppose to declare my plug in?  I did it in the res/xml/config/xml file

Thank you

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the reason that you can still use the plugin is because you either edited the wrong `config.xml` or did not run the cordova command line tools to propagate your changes to the correct `config.xml` file that is actually used by the app.

There are multiple `config.xml` files in different spots in a Cordova 3.x project. I'll try to give you an overview of the different locations of the files and how you should interact with them. Keep in mind that this is what happens when you use the CLI ([Command Line-interface](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface)) - I generated this directory structure by typing:

```
cordova create {MyApp}
cordova platform add android ios
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

Or prior to Cordova 3.1, replace the last line with:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
```

If you use just the platform level shell scripts to build the app (the "old" way that we did in Cordova 2.X), you can generally use the same workflow, but will need to [Use Plugman to Manage Plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html). (We are in the process of documenting these two different "workflows".)

First, when you create an app with `cordova create MyApp`, it will create an empty project structure like this:

```
/myApp/
        /www/           # This is where your "cross-platform' files go.
                        # The build tools copy these files over to the correct
                        # asset folder for each platform, like /assets/www/ for
                        # android or just /www/ for iOs. This is where you should
                        # be doing most/all of your work and is what should
                        # probably be version controlled.
        /platforms/
            /android/   # These will only appear after `cordova platform add`
            /ios/       # You should generally not touch these file as they are
                        # recreated quite often, although changes will persist.
        /plugins/
            /android/   # These will only appear after `cordova plugin add`. They
                        # pretty much just contain the native and web plugin code
                        # for all platforms that a plugin supports.
            /ios/
        /merges/        # This is where you can place platform-specific code that
                        # you write that will get merged in with your cross
                        # platform source, see the "customize each platform"
                        # section of: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html
```

You should make all of your changes to files in `/www/`, which is the "cross platform" source code. Whatever is in this folder will generally get copied and propagated to the platform level `www` folder when you use the command line tools (whether its `/assets/www` for Android or just `/www/` for iOS). This way, you only need a single source folder for your app - this is the folder that you should have under version control. Any app-wide configuration changes that you want should be made to the `config.xml` file placed at this location; later when you use the tools, this `config.xml` file will be copied (and sometimes modified with platform-specific configuration information) to the appropriate place for each app, like `/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml` (for android) or `/platforms/ios/AppName/config.xml` (for iOS).

Say you want to add the acceleration plugin by typing `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git`.
If you were to run a diff after this command, you will see the following files have been changed or added:

**plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information/**
    - This new folder contains all of the plugin meta information and code, including web and native code, for each supported platform

**plugins/android.json and plugins/ios.json**
    - Both of these files have been edited now to contain a reference to the network-information plugin. This is where you will see the config-munge bit of JSON. As you add more plugins, this file will continuously grow to reference all of them. This file tells the command line tools what code it needs to replace and in which files. For example, after adding the cordova-plugin-network-information plugin, you will see this in `/plugins/android.json`:

```
{
        "prepare_queue": {
            "installed": [],
            "uninstalled": []
        },
        "config_munge": {
            "res/xml/config.xml": {
                "/*": {
                    "<feature name=\"NetworkStatus\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager\" /></feature>": 1
                }
            },
            "AndroidManifest.xml": {
                "/*": {
                    "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE\" />": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "installed_plugins": {
            "org.apache.cordova.network-information": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.cordova.hellocordova"
            }
        },
        "dependent_plugins": {}
    }
```

This tells the scripts to write the feature name into `res/xml/config.xml` (again, for iOS, this will be different, since the app level config file is in a different location on iOS!), and also tells it to write **android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE** permission into AndroidManifest.xml (you won't find anything like this on iOS since no permissions are necessary.) (By the way, what gets written to each of these json files is defined in the plugin's plugin.xml file.)

**platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml**
    - The CLI tools took care of adding whichever permission were defined in the plugin's xml file to AndoridManifest. Yes, this happens when you do `cordova plugin add`. These permissions are directly copied from whatever is in the plugins/android.json file. These permissions are also deleted when you 'rm' a plugin. However, editing these files is done intelligenty, in that you can add custom things to AndroidManifest.xml and they will persist.

**platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js**
    - This file is buried inside the html resources that will make up your final app - these resources (pretty much anything in /platforms/) should not be edited by you because they will be replaced by the CLI tools quite frequently. This file is used by Cordova at runtime to load the plugin code that you added; it also takes care of mapping the JavaScript namespaces to the actual files (this is the "clobbers" declaration.) For example, I see:

```
{
    "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information/www/network.js",
    "id": "org.apache.cordova.network-information.network",
    "clobbers": [
        "navigator.connection",
        "navigator.network.connection"
    ]
}
```

this means that in your app code, `navigator.connection` and `navigator.network.connection` will both map to the code contained in `plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information/www/network.js`.

**platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml**
    - This is the platform-level config.xml file for Android. This file gets created by the CLI tools. A lot of the information that you write in your top level config.xml (/MyApp/www/config.xml) will get copied here, but not all of it (and there is some additional stuff, I'm not exactly sure where the additional stuff comes from.) This is the file that gets read by Android when it is running your app and it needs to check your config data. For example, Cordova Android code will use this to see which plugins are installed and which native classes map to which namespaces. I *think* the only way you could edit this is by using the /merges/ folder that I mentioned above.

**platforms/ios/{AppName}.xcodeprojcj/project.pbxproj**
    - The iOS equivalent of AndroidManifest.xml

**platforms/ios/{AppName}/config.xml**
    - This is the platform-level config.xml file for iOS. See how it is in a different spot than on Android? (eg, not in /res/xml/config.xml?) This file automatically gets updated by the CLI and you should not touch it.

**platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js**
    - The same file exists on Android (but in a different location) and has the same purpose: to help Cordova load your plugins at run time when somebody is using the app

I think that pretty much describes all of the files and folders that are used in a cordova project.

Hopefully now you can see that you should in fact only be editing the `/www/config.xml` file. This file will be used to construct the `/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml` and `/platforms/ios/{AppName}/config.xml`, which are used by Cordova when the packaged app is running. Parts of this file will be used to edit the AndroidManifest.xml and project.pbxprojc files (for Android and iOS, respectively.)

This explains why you were still able to use the accelerometer in your app even after deleting the `<feature name="Accelerometer">` lines - they were just being recopied into the platform level config.xml from the main app wide config.xml

I guess the only thing left to figure out is how you can edit platform specific configuration files; for example, how can you edit the AndroidManifest.xml file? Well, it turns out that you can just edit the `/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` file directly - the CLI is smart enough to not erase your customizations when it automatically adds or removes plugin permissions. So say for some reason you needed to support a lower version of Android than what Cordova supports, you can just change the  object and it will persist though your `cordova plugin add|rm {id}` calls.

I hope that clarifies things, feel free to ask any more questions!

Comment: This reply is EPIC. Thankyou - it's been crazily helpful to us

Comment: @obie awesome, I'm glad it has been helpful! I am trying to push a lot of this information into the real documentation, so if you think there is anything I omitted or should clarify, please let me know!

Comment: 1. The `/www/config.xml` file has now moved to the root directory `/config.xml` in the latest **Cordova 3.4.0-0.1.3**

Comment: 2. Is there a way to specify the modifications I want to do to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file directly within the `/config.xml` file, and the changes be auto-added to AndroidManifest.xml on doing a `cordova platform add android`?

Comment: I have almost cried when I have seen this answer :) SO beautifully explained and all the things I was confused about. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I use `cordova prepare` and it DOES replace whatever I have in my androidManifest.xml, so what is the way around that?

Comment: when using `cordova plugin add ...` it doesnt add these to your global config.xml. If you're using Phonegap build, it expects `<gap:plugin>` tags in your global config.xml, and you'll have to add them manually, as far as I can see. Read http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html

Comment: dude. you give the best answers. just wanted to say that!

Comment: Thanks @williamle8300. I should probably update this post since it has been a few years. I haven't used Cordova in a while though, maybe I should mark it as a community answer so people can update it?

Comment: Dude. Cordova needs to update their docs! If only they had hand-holding docs like these it would solve the problem in a more upstream fashion. Not to knock your employer or anything. It would increase Phonegap's friendliness to would-be adopters.

Answer (score 22):

Since **cordova 3.5**, we can persist plugins in `config.xml` file

```
<feature name="Network Information">
    <param name="id" value="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <param name="version" value="0.2.10" />
</feature>
```

The following command will fetch the plugins defined in config.xml

```
cordova restore plugins --experimental
```

The following command will write your current installed plugins in config.xml (3.5):

```
cordova save plugins --experimental
```

In 5.x and later:

```
cordova plugin save
```

Source: http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/07/10/tools-release.html

Answer (score 8):

Since **Cordova 5.0, yes**.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    ...
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.0" />
    ...
</ xml>
```

Mass saving plugins on an existing project :

```
$ cordova plugin save
```

On a fresh install (or after a clean), you can add all plugins with :

```
$ cordova prepare
```

Adding / updating / removing can also be done via cli :

```
$ cordova plugin add <plugin[@<version>] | directory | git_url> --save
$ cordova plugin update <plugin[@<version>] | directory | git_url> --save
$ cordova plugin remove <plugin> --save
```

There is no mass update for the moment. You can remove `plugins` directory then run a `$cordova prepare`.

Sources :

- http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/platform_plugin_versioning_ref_index.md.html
- https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html

Comment: There is a tool to update plugins : https://github.com/Rareloop/cordova-plugin-update

Answer (score 5):

Config.xml is mainly used by phonegap build.

If you're using phonegap 3 you should manage your plugins using the CLI:

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
```

The only config.xml you should edit is /www/config.xml, the others are automatically generated from that one when you build your project using:

```
$ phonegap build ios
```

Comment: Hi Sam, 

sure i download the plugin before i use it.
 But my question is why the plugin still works even when i dont include the mapping in the config.xml file? 
<feature name="Accelerometer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener" />
</feature>

Comment: I think its because only the phonegapbuild service needs to read your config.xml to see which plugins you have. If you just build locally then you can ignore it.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to check this for accelermator plugin:
[Phonegap Acceleramator plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer).

Also you can search there about any plugin you need

Comment: Hi Hazem, 

maybe the title of the question is misleading. I am able to use phonegap plugins. 

What is really my question is whether the plugin needs to be declared in the config.xml file. I noticed that even when i dont declare anything in the config.xml file , the plugin still works.

Comment: Yes, I got your question but the issue is phonegap is also reading plugins from cordova_plugins file

Comment: This may be because plugins was copied automatically to android folder but not iOS one, you may check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301518/phonegap-3-doesnt-copy-plugins-to-platforms-folder/18311741#18311741

Comment: by the way config.xml file is mainly used by phonegap build.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do 'cordova plugin add ALL_NEEDED_PLUGINS'? Checking plugins/* into scm doesn't seem to work properly so it seems when working in a team everyone has to repeat 'cordova plugin add ...' for each plugin.

Comment: Hi @s.Daniel, yes there is a way - create a "dependency plugin" that lists all of the needed ones, and install that, see: https://github.com/apache/cordova-mobile-spec/blob/master/dependencies-plugin/plugin.xml