# How to use the root phonegap www folder?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

When you create a phonegap project you start off with a root www folder, among other files.

```
/www
```

You then need to add devices to work, for example andriod or IOS. This then creates a new `www` folder inside the respective playforms:

```
 \platforms\android\assets\www
```

My question is, when using Android Studio how are you meant to use the root www folder? If at all? Which `www` folder am I meant to be building with?

It appears that when importing with Android Studio to go straight to the platform/andriod.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be editing the files in the /www/ file. When the CLI tools run `prepare`, which happens a lot, these files are copied into the appropriate platform's /www/ file. (This is because each platform can have it's web assets in a different location.) So do all of your work in the main /www/ folder - this is the one you should be putting into version control.

For more information try reading the documentation guide about `The config.xml file` which describes some of this: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

I've also written up a pretty long answer in another question that is pretty similar: [Should a phonegap plugin be declared in the config.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112436/should-a-phonegap-plugin-be-declared-in-the-config-xml-file/19125861#19125861)

Comment: Fantastic! and indeed this makes a whole lot more sense. Your answer is great, should beupvoted more for sure. I never knew that it complied down to various platforms. Although I must say its very very slow. I think I will work directly on the andriod folder and copy back up once its working. I can't keep doing `phonegap run android` after every change and waiting 10 mins.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it's making more sense. You can read in the CLI guide about how you can use the /merges/ folder to copy specific assets into only certain platforms. Also, I don't think `phonegap run android` should take 10 minutes...do you mean it takes 10 minutes to load up an android emulator? Or the tools take 10 minutes to copy things? Mine is like... a few seconds.

Comment: a few seconds would be lovely :) Nope, I don't use an emulator, I upload directly to my mobile and test there. A few seconds would be fantastic. Maybe I have assets that are too large. Maybe I need to refactor around things a bit.

Comment: Finally got an error: `[error] An error occurred while building the android project. Buildfile: C:\var\www\sexdiaries.co.uk\sdapp\platforms\android\build.xml
ERROR: Failed to build android project.` Humm

Comment: Actually I guess I have no idea if 10 minutes is normal or not, it depends on the assets that you are loadings. In my experience of loading test apps onto the device, it's always only a few seconds...but yeah I suppose if you are loading some huge files at install time, that could be part of the problem. If you just do `cordova create MyApp && cd myApp && cordova platform add android && cordova run`, does it still take 10 minutes to load the sample app? About your build error, you can try running `cordova -d` for more output or just cd into `platforms/android/bin` and `ant debug` to build...

Comment: I've learnt so much from all this cufluffel. Don't include `.git` in the www folder :)

Comment: I love your positive attitude! Good point about the `.git` folder, thx. I'd assume it's smart to not include any `.` files/folders at all.

Comment: yep, I just had no idea that phonegap people had magic up their sleves and worked out if you have a www folder in the root i'll look in there for the index.html. Genuis :p Argh, well 7 days of pure working everything about phonegap certainly gives you a solid understanding of it all :)

Comment: Also, now it only takes maybe 30/40 seconds to compile.

Comment: I have all my files in root www folder and when I run ios project it just displays old index.html from ios www folder. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain you're not propagating the files from the root www folder into the `/platforms/ios/` folder. Try running `cordova build` to build the application (first it runs `prepare` which copies all of the files into the correct place, then it runs `compile` which will compile the iOS app.)

Comment: @MBillau Thanks alot. They have a very silly documentation. Regards

Comment: @MBillau How I can set platform specific changes ? as when I build it replaces whole www folder. Basically I want to my app on android with different set of css. Regards

Comment: @MurtazaHussain There is an example of having specific CSS for Android at the end of the docs: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_customize_each_platform  You have to use the /merges/ folder.

Comment: Yes the docs do need work. I'm trying to improve them, so if you have any suggestions, please let me know or file a bug at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB

Comment: Its true though, sadly they do have poor documentation, so much so that people forget how amazing this phoengap thing is. Reminds of me facebook of 3/4 years ago. They'll get there, but its a shame that the easiest thing is missing. I guess they are upsetting so quickly that they can't keep it up to date.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your time. But I still prefer native apps over phonegap. its just a client request thats why. Regards