# Cordova/PhoneGap Plugin Development Workflow for Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I am developing a set of Cordova plugins.  The initial implementation will be Android only, so for now I am interested in being able to use ADT in Eclipse for plugin development.  I've read over the documentation and have been able to get the first plugin completed, but the workflow is a bit of a pain.  I couldn't find any docs or tools in Cordova that specifically support plugin development workflow.  I wonder if I am making it harder than it needs to be? Here is what I am doing.

The plugin is set up according to the cordova plugin spec.  I started by setting up the directory structure and editing the files in Sublime, so I have something like:

- $PLUGIN_ROOT

  - src

    - android

      - Plugin.java
  - www

    - plugin.js
  - plugin.xml

I set all of that up with boilerplate and an initial implementation.
Then to start testing, I created a cordova project, added the android platform, added my plugin and built:

```
cordova create testProject
cd testProject
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add $PLUGIN_ROOT
cordova build
cordova run
```

After doing all that, I import testProject/platforms/android into ADT and start editing Plugin.java and plugin.js, as well as assets/www to add a test harness.

Now, after getting everything working the way I want it to, I have to manually copy all of the changed files (plus any files I've added) back into the appropriate place under $PLUGIN_ROOT.  I also want to preserve my test harness, probably in $PLUGIN_ROOT/test.  This isn't too bad the first time, but after several iterations it's all getting a little unwieldy.  It also seems very error-prone to do it manually, but I can't really use a merge tool to do it for me, because the directory structure is different.  I could write a script, but then I'll be adding more maintenance overhead.  That being said, I'm currently planning on writing scripts to do this for each of the plugins that I am going to write.

Is there a better way?  I'd really like to hear how the cordova plugin developers manage this.  Thanks.

Comment: May i know your exact problem ...

Comment: @ManetiVinay: I explained it as well as I can in my question.  Basically, the development workflow I describe above is uncomfortable, but seems like the only possible approach due to the file organization required by the plugin specification.  I hope there is an approach that is better than the one I am using and someone will tell me what it is.

Comment: Export the project that you need to reuse and reimport and rename it again whenever you wanna use it

Answer (score 3):

You need an automated build tool like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) that [monitors](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) your plugin folder (e.g. $PLUGIN_ROOT) and [runs](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) the appropriate cordova commands whenever a file belonging to the plugin changes.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  It sounds like you are suggesting that I only edit the files in $PLUGIN_ROOT.  If I were to adopt that approach, I wouldn't be able to edit the files which are under debug, which is what I feel that I need to be able to do.  Maybe I'm missing something - if so, please elaborate on how your suggestion would help.  I had considered an approach based on a custom version of plugman that created symbolic links to all of the plugin files when you do 'cordova plugin add', but realized that when you do 'cordova prepare' it would copy the real files into the platform directory.

Comment: In that case is better to work on the files in your project and configure the grunt-watch task to automatically copy to your plugin master only the files that must be there when they change.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty since you took the time to answer and no one else did, but I'm not accepting the answer.  Although it is arguably better than manually copying all the files, it still requires a lot of manual configuration and maintenance on a per-plugin basis.  If I eventually get better results than expected by using grunt watch (or something similar) I will come back and accept your answer.  Thanks.