# AndroidManifest.xml doesn't get updated after build

Tags: cordova

I have been trying out different settings for android:windowSoftInputMode in config.xml for a Phonegap app. There did not seem to be any change so I checked which files in my project also have this variable after I did a `phonegap build android`. I found 4 other files:

`platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`
It still had the old value even though it was modified at the time I did the build

`platforms/android/ant-build/AndroidManifest.cordova.xml`
It still had the old value even though it was modified at the time I did the build

`platforms/android/bin/AndroidManifest.xml`
It had an even older value, and it was not modified

`platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml`
It had the new value

So is this why I didn't see any change in my app? Is this a bug?

I guess the workaround is to delete `platforms/android` and rebuild it, but I rather know if I am doing something wrong or not.

I am using Phonegap 3.5.0-0.20.4

Comment: use ```cordova prepare``` to update the platform projects after you edit the config.xml.

Comment: I am using phonegap and `build` is shorthand for `prepare` and `compile`, so i think I am already doing that...

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like this is a 'feature':

> ... how can you edit the AndroidManifest.xml file? Well, it turns out that you can just edit the /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml file directly - the CLI is smart enough to not erase your customizations when it automatically adds or removes plugin permissions.

Thanks to an answer from @MBillau ["Should a phonegap plugin be declared in the config.xml file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112436/should-a-phonegap-plugin-be-declared-in-the-config-xml-file/19125861#19125861)